# JQuery: Append to specific instance of multiple identical elements

Tags: jquery, html

I am appending html elements to my site via JQuery but I am concerned about their placement. What I'm trying to do might be easiest explained with a picture.

I've got two large windows and two small windows. The large windows (models) are what are appended to the body of my html with JQuery after my form (with id #modelform) is submitted. The smaller windows (walds) are what are appended to the body of my html after a wald form (with class .wald) is submitted. Each model window comes with its own wald form (the button Wald Test). What I would like is for the wald window that is returned after submission of a .wald form to be displayed to the right hand side of its associated model window, instead of underneath it.

Instead of appending the wald window to the html body I would like to do something like $wald_element.appendTo(**This wald form's containing window**) or something? Is this possible?

[image]

Here is the JQuery describing the process:

```
    var $counter = 0

    //When the model form is submitted...
    $("#modelform").submit(function() {

        $counter++;

        //It takes the values from the form (#mymodel)
        //and posts the values via AJAX to '/estimate'...
        $.post('/estimate', {name: $("#mymodel").val()}, function(data) {

            //And the value returned from '/estimate' is appended to the html body.
            var $model_var = data['title']
            var $model_element = $('<div class="window">' + $model_var + '<form class="waldform" action="#" method="post"><input type="text" id="waldnum" value="' + $counter + '" style="display:none"/><input type="submit" value="Wald Test" /></form></div><br>');       

            $('body').append($model_element) ;

            //When a waldform is submitted...
            $(".waldform").submit(function() {

                //The value in the form (#waldnum), which corresponds to a specific
                //value (model) returned from '/estimate', is posted via AJAX to '/wald'
                $.post('/wald', {name: $(this).find('#waldnum').val()}, function(data) {

                    //And the value returned from '/wald'is appended to the html body
                    var $wald_var = data['title']
                    var $wald_element = $('<div class="wald">' + $wald_var + '</div><br>');

                    $("body").append($wald_element);

                                });

                            return false ;

                            });

                       });

                    $(".waldform").off() ;

                return false ;

                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the form that was submitted using `event.target` in the `submit` function, and use functions like `.parent()` to traverse the DOM and find the element (the window in your case) that you want to append the Wald element to.

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    ...
    $(event.target).parent().append($wald_element);
    ...
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sz7UY/)

However, the way that's displayed will depend on the structure of your HTML and CSS. You could edit those so that the item is appended to a `div` containing the main window. Or, if these windows are moveable and you're using absolute positioning, you can set the position of the new Wald element based on the `offset` of the Model element.

```
$wald_element.css({
        position: 'absolute', 
        top: target.offset().top,
        left: target.offset().left + target.width()
    });
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sz7UY/3/)

That example uses jQuery UI to allow the elements to be moved, but if you're using something else or the windows aren't moveable, it should still work.

Comment: YAY! Exactly what I was looking for! :)